# 20.04 trouble with Logitech M705 mouse scroll wheel

Tags: mouse, logitech

I have used the M705 wireless mouse for years on the same machine, Ubuntu 14.04, without any problems.  I upgraded to 20.04, and have had problems with the scroll wheel ever since.

The mouse settings are as much as is allowed by the system controls, and all buttons work well for the most part.  When the scroll wheel works, it works as expected.
However, at startup or at resume-from-sleep on a desktop machine, the scroll wheel always fails to work correctly.  It takes multiple clicks of the wheel to effect any movement, whereas a normal single click would be needed in correct operation, i.e., page scroll, desktop workspace scroll, etc.  Most times I can turn off the mouse (mouse power-off switch) for about 3 seconds, then back on, and the problem will be fixed, or it may take sever attempts at this.  Other times, it's necessary to fully reboot and go through the off-on steps to restore correct operation.

Imwheel does not fix this problem, so I don't use it; I don't start it.  The only remedy is the above action.

Is there any driver change or setting that can fix this?  I haven't discovered exactly what goes wrong to cause the issue, just that scrolling doesn't work normally (I also have a wireless keyboard on the same key; it works fine, but is usually left turned off until specifically needed).  Gnome desktop is in use, with several extensions, etc., and all of the same add-ons that were used in Ubuntu 14.04.  I do use Solaar, but it doesn't seem to have any effect relating to the issue.  Solaar is always started with the machine boot (as always was with 14.04).

Does anyone have suggestions for a permanent fix?

Comment: 14.04 used the Unity 7 desktop; and if you were using GNOME 3 on 14.04; as it reached EOL in 2017-April, Ubuntu 20.04 didn't yet exist for ~3 years.. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Unity 7 desktop reached EOL before 20.04 too (2019-April); so your switching from 14.04 to 20.04 & using the same extensions doesn't fit (*timewise*, *security-wise* etc).   Your *non-standard* & *unsupported* upgrade path implies loads of potential problems (let alone security risks! but maybe your box was off-line).  I'd likely test a 20.04 fresh system on thumb-drive to see if issue occurs...

Comment: No, I'm afraid you misunderstand.  I'm not using any part of the 14.04 installation.  It's an entirely clean installation of 20.04 on a brand new drive.  What I said is I have selected all of the same utilities and add-ons as were used before (except for a small few cases where they no longer exist.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 was the 2014-April release of Ubuntu, used a different desktop and thus was a rather different system to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS or the 2020-April release.  There are six years between them !   Your 14.04 discussion just clouds the issue & I don't understand what you're trying to get across with it, as you've provided no specifics except for comparing two rather different products six years apart (with different software stacks due to the six years between them).

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, the problem may be related to Solaar, after all.  The version is probably newer than the version used in 14.04, and at this point, I don't remember if any options were used previously, but I seem to have fixed the problem.  I turned on the option for smooth scrolling of the mouse in Solaar, and the problem simply has gone away.  The Solaar build is frequently updated, and is now 1.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem, setting to smooth scrolling APPARENTLY fixed it !

I need a few days to be sure.